How to properly load .dat file in r without variable labels (NBER CPS data)
I am trying to load into r and wrangle data from the CPS (Current Population Survey) which can be downloaded at this link. There is an ostensible codebook for the information on variables and the ranges of each variable as coded in files such as those at this link and this link (Both examples are for the 2004 dataset). However, when I try to load the data file into r, I encounter issues where the variables seem to match up but there are gaps. If I open the 2004 file with the following code:
library(data.table)
cps_raw <- read.delim("cpsmay04.dat", header = FALSE, sep = "")


This gives me the following output:

which differs from when I change the separator to be a full space:
library(data.table)
cps_raw <- read.delim("cpsmay04.dat", header = FALSE, sep = " ")


giving the following output:

I am inclined to think the first one is correct, though I'm not sure it gets all the columns correct, since the spaces between values are different. The codebook does not seem to indicate how the data should be loaded in, and I am only used to working with .csv, .dta, .xlsx or .sav files. If the first option is correct, how do I know which variable is which? Do I simply index by the codebook? If so, is there a more efficient way to rename the variables throughout the dataset when loading it into r? Am I loading it incorrectly such that the variable names are not loaded, or must this be done manually? If it must be done manually, is there a way to only load part of the dataframe (certain columns) to not have to deal with many variables that are not necessary, since there are so many?
UPDATE to troubleshoot Rui's solution
While the solution mostly appears to work, the 04 file seems not to take.
For example, when using the 1997 file, the HURESPLI variable has no NA values and no -1 values, which are not detailed in the variable codebook (values are between 0-99). The variable distribution is the following:

However, when trying to load the same variable for the 2004 file now there are many -1's which do not match the variable codebook as a defined value. This variable should be available for all individual observations, and should not be repeated for values with the same household ID (HRHHID) since it represents a unique respondent within a household:

It also produces a new variable not specified in the .ddf file, HURESPLI_61 which seems to be the same variable plus the column number after the HURESPLI column, which has a different set of values:

This no longer has all the -1 values, but I would still be skeptical of it being the true values of HURESPLI, because the numbers above 0 should represent the number of the respondent within household in the case where there is more than 1 respondent per household (so there should be mostly 1, since most respondents would be in a multiperson household, but information on other household members would not be as often provided. But there being only 103 zeros in the 2004 file after 9000 in the 97 file leaves me skeptical.
Is there any reason why the code would be creating additional columns, and can I be sure that the variables are accurate, as HURESPLI does not look right?

the first one means any amount of white space is the delimiter, the second means exactly one space. read.delim is not from data.table btw

Neither is corrrect.  This is fixed width data. You need to use the accompanying ddf file and specify the widths of the fields.  See ?read.fwf.

The following code was tested with the data in the question link, no need for SPSS , SAS or STATA files.
The main problem is to parse the .ddf file, which is not that difficult considering that the data width lines always begin with the character "D". Filter those lines, split by spaces and coerce the two last columns to integer. Then use column "SIZE" as column widths.
process_ddf <- function(file) {
  ddf <- readLines(file)
  i <- grep("^D ", ddf)
  mat <- ddf[i] |>
    strsplit(" +") |>
    sapply(`[`, -1L) |>
    t()
  out <- mat |>
    as.data.frame() |>
    setNames(c("DATA", "SIZE", "BEGIN"))
  out[-1L] <- lapply(out[-1L], as.integer)
  if(anyNA(out[-1L])) {
    mat[, -1L] <- apply(mat[, -1L], 2L, \(x) gsub("\\D", "", x))
    out[, -1L] <- apply(mat[, -1L], 2L, as.integer)
  }
  out
}

data_file <- "cpsmay04.dat"
ddf_link <- "http://data.nber.org/cps/cpsmay04.ddf"
d <- process_ddf(ddf_link)
# some columns are fillers, need to make unique col names
filler <- grep("FILLER", d$DATA)
padding <- grep("PADDING", d$DATA)
d$DATA[filler] <- paste(d$DATA[filler], filler, sep = "_")
d$DATA[padding] <- paste(d$DATA[padding], padding, sep = "_")

# now read in the data
# read.fwf is painfully slow, use readr::read_fwf
library(readr)
cpsmay04 <- read_fwf(data_file, fwf_widths(d$SIZE, d$DATA))

# optional
spc <- spec(cpsmay04)
spc


Thank you so much, this works perfectly!

As a follow up, is there any way to adapt this to deal with the 1991 file, which doesn't have a .ddf file linked? It would be great to load that as well.

Sorry, I actually have another question. I think your code works nearly perfectly, but some of the files don't work perfectly. I found it works perfectly for the 1997, but there seem to be some issues with 2004. For example, it doesn't accurately produce the HURESPLI column, as the values in it are messed up. However, it does produce an unlist variable HURESPLI_61, which seems to have values from the PULINENO variable. Would you know why this would be or how to fix this in the code you provided? Thanks again!

I cannot find anything wrong with cpsmay04, can you describe how some values are messed up?

Thanks for responding @Rui, I've added examples/explanation of the issue with screenshots as an edit to the question above. Thanks for your help!

@flâneur - 1) There is an error in Rui's code that affects the names but not the data.  d$DATA[filler] <- paste(d$DATA, filler, sep = "_") should be d$DATA[filler] <- paste(d$DATA[filler], filler, sep = "_") and likewise for padding.  2) -1 is a valid value as defined at the top of the ddf file Additional valid entries for unedited items: -1 (blank) .. 3) Most seriously there is an error in the 2004 ddf file - variable 25 (filler) should have a width of 3 not 2, so you need to do d <- process_ddf(ddf_link); d[25, 2] <- 3. Then we can check all widths are correct ...

... by using all((cumsum(d$SIZE)+1 == dplyr::lead(d$BEGIN)), na.rm = TRUE).

Neither method 1 nor method 2 is correct. Please refer to attachment 6 and attachment 7 in the PDF file for the column definitions. Or here for scripts which can be directly used in SAS, SPSS and Stata.
In R, you can use package "asciiSetupReader" to deal with .sps or .sas set up files.
library(asciiSetupReader)

cps2004may <- read_ascii_setup(
  data = dat_path,
  setup_file = sps_path
)

